# HTTP Options method url different then specified endpoint url

Tags: node.js, express, http, https

I have deployed a Node app to Heroku and set the URL in my client to send HTTP requests to. But when I sent a POST request, the OPTIONS request that gets sent before is being sent to a different request URL.

Is there a way that I can change what URL the OPTIONS request is being sent to?

URL that my client is using:

```
https://frozen-cove-78793.herokuapp.com/api
```

OPTIONS error in console when sending a POST request. URL in the error is:

```
https://young-river-73543.herokuapp.com/api/users
```

[image: Error in console]

Any idea how to change the OPTIONS request URL?

Comment: Could you add the code with the XHR Request (Client Side) ?

Comment: As the error message says, you have a CORS problem. `https://frozen-cove-78793.herokuapp.com` & `https://young-river-73543.herokuapp.com` are not the same domain. Look up what CORS is and how to configre it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Ok, but nowhere is my app is sending a request to `https://young-river-73543.herokuapp.com` so I am not sure why there is being an OPTIONS request there before the POST when the POST is calling `https://frozen-cove-78793.herokuapp.com`.